# Referencing a field of an object in another object created by its constructor

Tags: java, arraylist, constructor, nullpointerexception

the object creator

```
ObjectCreator.java

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class ObjectCreator {

    List<CreatedObject> objects;
    static ObjectCreator objectCreator;

    public ObjectCreator() {
        objects = new ArrayList<CreatedObject>();
        CreatedObject createdObject = new CreatedObject(9); //second object
    }

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        objectCreator = new ObjectCreator(); //first object
    }
}
```

the created object

```
CreatedObject.java

class CreatedObject {

    public CreatedObject() {
        ObjectCreator.objectCreator.objects.add(this); //adds itself
                                                       //nullpointer here
    }
}
```

Above is the exemplification of my problem. I get a nullpointer exception at the line `ObjectCreator.objectCreator.objects.add(this);` because objectCreator (in class ObjectCreator) is null. I believe this is because the constructor for objectCreator (in class ObjectCreator) has not concluded and therefore the object has not been given a value.

In my actual program, I have a class in charge of creating objects based on an algorithm. This algorithm is fed information through the constructor parameters of the class. At the end of the constructor, I want to have multiple (non static) ArrayLists, each filled with references to all of the different objects of each type that have been created. I want these objects, in their constructors, to add themselves to the ArrayList. i.e. `object1 creates object2 creates object3 adds itself to ArrayList stored in object1` This approach has obviously proven unfruitful.

The question: What should i do to achieve these results (ArrayLists filled with objects created in the constructor of my ObjectCreator class) in a clean and efficient way? This seems like a pretty rudimentary function that would be necessary in many programs, so how is it done?

Comment: Update: the reference `objectCreator = new ObjectCreator();` is not actually assigned until after the conclusion of the constructor of `ObjectCreator`. If I try to use the reference in `CreatedObject`, I get a `nullpointer`. The answer lies in finding a new reference. How would I create a new, useable reference?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in accessing that static field. The assignment in `main` doesn't happen until after the constructor is complete, but you're trying to read it in the inner class constructor.

If you're going to have an inner (non-static) class, just use the enclosing class's instance list.

Comment: Ok. so you are saying that I actually _can_ reference the ArrayList because it has already been initialized, but i cannot do it using the reference that has not yet been created in `main`. That is what I understand at least. How would I go about referencing the enclosing class's instance list without the non-existent reference created in main?

Comment: Replace `objectCreator` with `this`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I can't see where replacing `objectCreator` with `this` would make a different reference. I might be missing it. What I do understand from your answer, though, is that I need a different reference to objectCreator, which can be passed through a parameter of the constructor of createdObject. This makes the program operate properly. Is there any other reference alternative available than passing one through the constructor? I like minimalistic parameters. If not this is still a perfectly acceptable alternative.

Comment: Inner classes have an implicit reference to their containing classes. *Try* the solution I suggested.

Comment: I tried the solution you provided with your comment. I get a compile error `No enclosing instance of the type ObjectCreator is accessible in scope`. It seems, though, that this is a different issue, perhaps with visibility? Anyway, your answer was excellent and should work with tweaking. If you have advice on the error I would love it, but you answered my original question with the qualified `this`.

Comment: Wait, are those two in the same file but not actually nested? (The mobile formatting left a lot to be desired.)

Comment: Yeah those are not nested. Sorry I wasn't sure how to present two different classes efficiently so I put them in the same quote box. I can see how that would have been odd to see format-wise. I am a noob after all ;)

Comment: If your answer was more geared toward a nested class, i'm going to unaccept to see what other people think. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score -1):

You can calling a static field which mean the constructor is not called.

```
ObjectCreator.objectCreator.objects.add(this);
```

You can do this instead in the class to initialize the static field:

```
static ObjectCreator objectCreator = new ObjectCreator();
```